# case with SQL order by clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need help with the SQL `ORDER BY` clause. In my table below I want to order all the items so child items immediately follow their parent item. For example, in the below list, the last item has the `ParentId` value of 17 and follows an item whose `ParentId` is 23, but it should actually appear with the other `ParentId=17` items.

[image]

In a similar way, if I later add a row with `ParentId = 9`, it should appear with items whose `ParentId` is 9 and not at the end of the list.

How should I sort my items to achieve the necessary output?

Comment: What query have you tried so far? Please also post your table structure

Comment: I've read this twice and I can't figure out what it is you're trying to do.  Comments: There are more than two zeros, and what you're seeing is most likely insertion order.  Also, is this formatted in SO in the way you intended??

Comment: Assuming you want to preserve the order of the 0s, what is the other field in the table that determines this order as it stands? you cannot use the 'natural' un-ordered order (i.e a select without an order by)

Comment: it is not clear what you are looking for. can you post the expected results?

Comment: I paraphrased your question a little. Please review my edit in case I missed something or got something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY
  ISNULL(NULLIF(ParentId, 0), Id),
  Id  /* or maybe Level? */
```